# FFmpeg4Android how to stop processing?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-processing

I have been successfully setup and starting ffmpeg4android as described here http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html and all goes fine. But what if I want to stop processing before it will be finished. I call fExit(Context context) method from LoadJNI class and nothing happens. Does someone know how correctly stop ffmpeg4android processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to the last version 3.22_02